# Fill a closed path in easeljs

Tags: svg, easeljs, createjs

Is there a way to fill a closed drawn path in easeljs?  I have along string of mt(x_t,y_t).lt(x_(t+1),y_(t+1)) that draws a wacky shape.  the shape closes off, but I can't find a way to have it actually fill in the closed area.  Any ideas?

T is how many coordinates there are to connect, [round.X, round.Y] is the Tx2 array of coordinate pairs, ghf is the graphics object.  xline.y is just a the lowest y value.

```
    for(var i=0;i<T;i++){

        x0 = round.X[i];
        y0 = round.Y[i];

        // scale for drawing
        px0 = Math.round(xscale * x0);
        py0 = Math.round(yscale * y0) + xline.y;

        if(x0>gp.xmin){ // if not first point ...
            ghf.mt(prevx,prevy).lt(px0,py0); // draw line from prev point to this point
        }

        // set this point as prev point
        prevx = px0;
        prevy = py0;
    }
// fill out thing
ghf.mt(prevx,prevy).lt(px0,xline.y);
ghf.mt(px0,xline.y).lt(0,xline.y);

x0 = round.X[0];
y0 = round.Y[0];
px0 = Math.round(xscale * x0);
py0 = Math.round(yscale * y0) + xline.y;
ghf.mt(0,xline.y).lt(px0,py0);
ghf.f('red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not very helpful, but I think what you need is the `beginFill` method. See [link](http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Graphics.html#method_beginFill).

You can use it like this:

```
var ball = new createjs.Shape();
ball.graphics.setStrokeStyle(5, 'round', 'round');
ball.graphics.beginStroke(('#000000'));
ball.graphics.beginFill("#FF0000").drawCircle(0,0,50);
ball.graphics.endStroke();
ball.graphics.endFill();
ball.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1, 'round', 'round');
ball.graphics.beginStroke(('#000000'));
ball.graphics.moveTo(0,0);
ball.graphics.lineTo(0,50);
```